# NewThreadScheduler.Default schedules all work on same thread

Tags: c#, concurrency, system.reactive

I'm currently trying to wrap my head around concurrency with RX .NET and getting confused by something. I want to run four relatively slow tasks in parallel, so I assumed `NewThreadScheduler.Default` would be the way to go, as it *"Represents an object that schedules each unit of work on a separate thread."*.

Here's my setup code:

```
    static void Test()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Starting. Thread {0}", Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);

        var query = Enumerable.Range(1, 4);
        var obsQuery = query.ToObservable(NewThreadScheduler.Default);
        obsQuery.Subscribe(DoWork, Done);

        Console.WriteLine("Last line. Thread {0}", Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
    }

    static void DoWork(int i)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(500);
        Console.WriteLine("{0} Thread {1}", i, Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
    }

    static void Done()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Done. Thread {0}", Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
    }
```

I assumed the "X Thread Y" would output a different thread id every time, however the actual output is:

```
Starting. Thread 1
Last line. Thread 1
1 Thread 3
2 Thread 3
3 Thread 3
4 Thread 3
Done. Thread 3
```

All the work is being one on the same new thread in sequential order, which isn't what I was expecting.

I'm assuming I'm missing something, but I can't figure out what.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There are two parts to an observable query, the `Query` itself and the `Subscription`. (This is also the difference between the ObserveOn and SubscribeOn operators.)

Your `Query` is

```
Enumerable
    .Range(1, 4)
    .ToObservable(NewThreadScheduler.Default);
```

This creates an observable that *produces values* on the default `NewThreadScheduler` for that system.

Your Subscription is

```
obsQuery.Subscribe(DoWork, Done);
```

This runs `DoWork` for each value produced by the `Query` and `Done` when the `Query` finishes with an `OnComplete` call. I don't think there are any guarantees about what thread the functions in the subscribe method will be called on, in practice if all values of the query are produced on the same thread that is the thread the subscription will be run on. It appears they are also making it so all of the subscription calls are made on the same thread which is most likely done to get rid of a lot of common multi-threading errors.

So you have two issues, one is with your logging, if you change your `Query` to

```
Enumerable
    .Range(1, 4)
    .Do(x => Console.WriteLine("Query Value {0} produced on Thread {1}", x, Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
    .ToObservable(NewThreadScheduler.Default);
```

You'll see each value produced on a new thread.

The other issue is one of the intention and design of Rx. It's *intended* that the `Query` is the long-running process and the `Subscription` is a short method that deals with the results. If you want to run a long running function as an Rx Observable your best option is to use [Observable.ToAsync](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reactive.linq.observable.toasync%28v=vs.103%29.aspx).

Comment: Thank you for this. Not only are you clarifying what I'm doing wrong, but I also think what you say regarding the intention of Rx makes a lot of sense.

Comment: The above answer seems to be outdated, Do method is no longer is available on Enumerable.

Comment: For the Do method to work, you need to install System.Interactive nuget package