# Reactive Extension subscribe is blocking my WPF application

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, soap, system.reactive

I rewrote some old async code of mine that makes that makes SOAP calls. The fetch() method would go out, get the result from the SOAP interface, and then add it to a DataTable that is bound to my WPF view. The new code uses Reactive Extensions to get a list of strings and creates an IObservable from the list. I thought it would return the results asynchronously, but the entire UI locks up until the entire result set is ready. I'm new to Reactive Extensions so I'm hoping I'm just missing something simple.

The Code:

(from click event)

```
   private void fetchSoapRows()
   {
       var strings = (txtInput.Text.Split('*')).ToObservable();
       strings.Subscribe(s=> SoapQueryEngine.Fetch(s));
   }
```

Also, does anyone know how I could write a test to make certain this method doesn't block the application in the future?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two parts to an observable query, the `Query` itself and the `Subscription`.

Your `Query` is an `IEnumerable<string>` producing values as fast as the computer can do it.

Your Subscription is

```
SoapQueryEngine.Fetch(s);
```

This runs `Fetch` for each string produced by the `Query` in the Subscriber thread which tends to be the thread where you're setting up your Subscription (although it isn't necessarily).

The issue has to do with the intention and design of Rx. It's *intended* that the `Query` is the long-running process and the `Subscription` is a short method that deals with the results. If you want to run a long running function as an Rx Observable your best option is to use [Observable.ToAsync](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reactive.linq.observable.toasync%28v=vs.103%29.aspx).

You should also take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17772373/21186) to see a similar problem which shows more of what's going on in the background.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing inherently concurrent about Rx.  If you want to make your calls to Fetch you will need to change SoapQueryEngine so that it is async or call it on another thread and then bring the results back to the UI thread.

Comment: This is just not true. Rx is very much "inherently asynchronous". Rx is based on call backs and the observer pattern. I think you mean "There is nothing inherently *concurrent* about Rx".

Answer (score 0):

Try this way. Instead of subscribing to the event text changed event, create an observable on the event and observe it on the thread pool:

```
Observable.FromEventPattern(<subscribe event>, <unsubscribe event>)
.ObserveOn(ThreadPoolScheduler.Instance)
.SelectMany(s => s.Split('*'))
.Subscribe(s=> SoapQueryEngine.Fetch(s));
```

Comment: That won't work because it's the subscriber thread doing the long running task and the observer thread coming from the thread pool.