# subscribe_on with from_iterable/range in RxPY

Tags: python, scheduler, reactive-programming, rx-py

I'm trying to get my head around scheduling in reactive extensions for python. I would like to use `subscribe_on` to process multiple observables in parallel. This works fine if the observable is created with `just`, but not if for example `range` or `from_` are used.

`just` defaults to `Scheduler.immediate`, while other generators default to `Scheduler.current_thread`. Which causes the difference, but feels inconsistent to me. Probably because I don't grasp the full problem.
Consider the following example:

```python
import rx
from rx.concurrency.scheduler import Scheduler
import time
import threading


def work(x):
    print "processing %s on thread %s" % (x, threading.currentThread().name)
    time.sleep(1)


def finish(x):
    print "finished %s on thread %s" % (x, threading.currentThread().name)


# Creates new thread (I like)
rx.Observable.just(3)\
    .do_action(work)\
    .subscribe_on(Scheduler.new_thread)\
    .subscribe(finish)

# Runs on MainThread (I don't like)
rx.Observable.range(1, 3) \
    .do_action(work) \
    .subscribe_on(Scheduler.new_thread) \
    .subscribe(finish)
```

It works with `observe_on` or if the Scheduler is passed directly to the generator, but I would like to decouple observable creation from processing and achieve something like this:

```python
import rx
from rx.concurrency.scheduler import Scheduler
import time
import threading


def work(x):
    print "processing %s on thread %s" % (x, threading.currentThread().name)
    time.sleep(1)


def finish(x):
    print "finished %s on thread %s" % (x, threading.currentThread().name)


def factory_single():
    return rx.Observable.just(1).do_action(work)


def factory_multiple():
    return rx.Observable.range(2, 4).do_action(work)


def process(factory):
    factory().subscribe_on(Scheduler.new_thread).subscribe(finish)

# Creates a new thread (I like)
process(factory_single)

# Runs on MainThread (I don't like)
process(factory_multiple)
```

Am I misunderstanding `subscribe_on`? Is my approach wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are three actions in your example that can be scheduled independently:

1. Data feed action. `just` and `range` use different schedulers by default, but there is not much difference between them. Both feed in initial values on the current thread. You can override their default schedulers to whatever you wish by passing it as a parameter to these methods.
2. Subscribe action. Uses `Scheduler.current_thread` by default. I.e. it is executed on the same thread as data feed action. Can be overridden by `subscribe_on` method.
3. Observe (`on_next`, `on_error`, `on_completed`) action. Uses `Scheduler.current_thread` by default. I.e. it is executed on the same thread as subscribe action. Can be overridden by `observe_on` method.

In case you override scheduler for only one of these actions the others shall follow as described above.

**About schedulers**

`Scheduler.immediate` does not really schedule anything. It invokes action immediately on the same thread where it was scheduled.

`Scheduler.current_thread` avoids recursion by queuing actions but still invokes action on the same thread where it was scheduled.

`Scheduler.new_thread` launches *single* background thread to execute actions one after another.

`Scheduler.timeout` launches new background thread for every action it needs to execute.

**Attempt parallel processing**

The most appropriate method for scheduling work in different threads seems to be `observe_on`.

The problem though is that there is no `thread_pool` scheduler in RxPy right now. `new_thread` scheduler launches just one thread so it will not help you much.

`timeout` scheduler can be used to go parallel but it offers no control on the number of concurrent threads, therefore explosive growth in the number of concurrent tasks can overflow memory and effectively crash your system.

**NOT a bug in observe_on**

I tried running your example with `observe_on(Scheduler.timeout)` but the tasks still did not go in parallel. After looking into the RxPy source I have discovered that it schedules next event only after current event completes, which effectively *disables parallel processing*. My first reaction was to report a [bug](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxPY/issues/67) in `observe_on` implementation.

But after further investigation I've found that serial execution is not a bug but rather [intended behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16660155/697313).

**Proper way to execute tasks in parallel**

Here is the code that works (based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19015683/697313)):

```
Observable.range(1, 3) \
  .select_many(lambda i: Observable.start(lambda: work(i), scheduler=Scheduler.timeout)) \
  .observe_on(Scheduler.event_loop) \
  .subscribe(finish)
```

`Observable.start` creates *asynchronous* observable that is scheduled on a separate thread via `Scheduler.timeout`.

`observe_on(Scheduler.event_loop)` is optional. It forces `finish` method for all items to be called on the same thread.

Please note that there is no guarantee that `finish` method is called in initial `range` order.

Comment: I assumed that `Scheduler.new_thread` creates a new thread for every event. Thanks!

Comment: `Scheduler.timeout` is the one that creates new thread for every action. But it does not help due to design bug in `observe_on`. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Sorry it was not a bug with `observe_on`. I've updated the answer with working code.