# How to wait for RxPy parallel threads to complete

Tags: python, multithreading, python-multithreading, reactivex, rx-py

Based on this [excellent SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32450932/subscribe-on-with-from-iterable-range-in-rxpy/33847875#33847875) I can get multiple tasks working in parallel in RxPy, my problem is how do you wait for them to all complete? I know using threading I can do `.join()` but there doesn't seem to be any such option with Rx Schedulers. `.to_blocking()` doesn't help either, the MainThread completes before all notifications have fired and the complete handler has been called. Here's an example:

```
from __future__ import print_function
import os, sys
import time
import random
from rx import Observable
from rx.core import Scheduler
from threading import current_thread

def printthread(val):
    print("{}, thread: {}".format(val, current_thread().name))

def intense_calculation(value):
    printthread("calc {}".format(value))
    time.sleep(random.randint(5, 20) * .1)
    return value

if __name__ == "__main__":
    Observable.range(1, 3) \
        .select_many(lambda i: Observable.start(lambda: intense_calculation(i), scheduler=Scheduler.timeout)) \
        .observe_on(Scheduler.event_loop) \
        .subscribe(
            on_next=lambda x: printthread("on_next: {}".format(x)),
            on_completed=lambda: printthread("on_completed"),
            on_error=lambda err: printthread("on_error: {}".format(err)))

    printthread("\nAll done")
    # time.sleep(2)
```

### Expected output

```
calc 1, thread: Thread-1
calc 2, thread: Thread-2
calc 3, thread: Thread-3

on_next: 2, thread: Thread-4
on_next: 3, thread: Thread-4
on_next: 1, thread: Thread-4
on_completed, thread: Thread-4
All done, thread: MainThread
```

### Actual output

```
calc 1, thread: Thread-1
calc 2, thread: Thread-2
calc 3, thread: Thread-3

All done, thread: MainThread
```

### Actual output if I uncomment the sleep call

```
calc 1, thread: Thread-1
calc 2, thread: Thread-2
calc 3, thread: Thread-3

All done, thread: MainThread
on_next: 2, thread: Thread-4
on_next: 3, thread: Thread-4
on_next: 1, thread: Thread-4
on_completed, thread: Thread-4
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For `ThreadPoolScheduler`, you can:

1. scheduler = ThreadPoolScheduler(pool_size)
2. parallel calls.
3. `scheduler.executor.shutdown()`

then, you can get all results once all are done.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you Kaka, scheduler.executor.shutdown() did it.

Answer (score 7):

Posting complete solution here:

```
from __future__ import print_function
import os, sys
import time
import random
from rx import Observable
from rx.core import Scheduler
from threading import current_thread
from rx.concurrency import ThreadPoolScheduler

def printthread(val):
    print("{}, thread: {}".format(val, current_thread().name))

def intense_calculation(value):
    printthread("calc {}".format(value))
    time.sleep(random.randint(5, 20) * .1)
    return value

if __name__ == "__main__":
    scheduler = ThreadPoolScheduler(4)

    Observable.range(1, 3) \
        .select_many(lambda i: Observable.start(lambda: intense_calculation(i), scheduler=scheduler)) \
        .observe_on(Scheduler.event_loop) \
        .subscribe(
            on_next=lambda x: printthread("on_next: {}".format(x)),
            on_completed=lambda: printthread("on_completed"),
            on_error=lambda err: printthread("on_error: {}".format(err)))

    printthread("\nAll done")
    scheduler.executor.shutdown()
    # time.sleep(2)
```

Comment: Some operators doesn't work on RXpy version3 and select_many doesn't seem to exist anymore.

Answer (score 4):

Use [`run()`](https://rxpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference_observable.html#rx.Observable.run) to wait for RxPy parallel threads to complete.

[BlockingObservables](https://rxpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/migration.html#blocking-observable) have been removed from RxPY v3.

```
from threading import current_thread
import rx, random, multiprocessing, time
from rx import operators as ops

def intense_calculation(value):
   delay = random.randint(5, 20) * 0.2
   time.sleep(delay)
   print("From adding_delay: {0} Value : {1} {2}".format(current_thread(), value, delay))
   return (value[0], value[1]+ " processed")

thread_pool_scheduler = rx.scheduler.NewThreadScheduler()

my_dict={'A':'url1', 'B':'url2', 'C':'url3'}

new_dict = rx.from_iterable(my_dict.items()).pipe(
    ops.flat_map(lambda a: rx.of(a).pipe(
        ops.map(lambda a: intense_calculation(a)),
        ops.subscribe_on(thread_pool_scheduler)
    )),
    ops.to_dict(lambda x: x[0], lambda x: x[1])
).run()

print("From main: {0}".format(current_thread()))
print(str(new_dict))
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. `scheduler.executor.shutdown()` is a blocking method to return until all threads are free. But what actually need is to wait for the the observalbe to complete.