# How to make NewThreadScheduler.Default schedules work on differnet threads

Tags: system.reactive

Trying to wrap my head around Rx, the following code does not seem to work as I wanted it to run on different threads. What am I missing?

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reactive.Concurrency;
using System.Reactive.Linq;
using System.Threading;


namespace OverviewConsoleApp
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Thread {0}", Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);

            var query = Enumerable.Range(1, 5).Select(n => n);

            IObservable<int> observableQuery = query.ToObservable(NewThreadScheduler.Default);
            observableQuery.Subscribe(ProcessNumber, ImDone);

        }

        static void ProcessNumber(int number)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0} Thread {1}", number, Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
        }

        static void ImDone()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("I am done!");
        }
    }
}
```

**NewThreadScheduler.Default** schedules all work on same thread. I am trying to schedule them on different threads.

I  have seen this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17775727/1977871), but the answer suggested there seem to be outdated, because IEnumerable no longer has Do method.
Can somebody help me how to run them on different threads?

The [System.Reactive nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Reactive/) package has to be installed for the above to run.

Comment: Man, this is one of those cases which comes crawling out of [the pit of success](https://blog.codinghorror.com/falling-into-the-pit-of-success/).

Comment: `NewThreadScheduler` uses `EventLoopScheduler` internally which will create a new thread only when there are no currently running `OnNext` handlers - if one is running then it will add the new `OnNext` to the same thread. The reason for this is that thread creation is expensive so it's best to re-use when possible. Also, remember that Rx runs the `OnNext` in series anyway so this strategy is a very good optimisation.

Comment: Yes, now I realize, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`someEnumerable.ToObservable(scheduler)` schedules the all items of the observable to run on that scheduler. If you want to schedule each individual item, you'll have to turn each item into its own observable. The following does that:

```
IObservable<int> observableQuery = query
    .ToObservable()
    .SelectMany(i => Observable.Return(i).ObserveOn(NewThreadScheduler.Default /*Or TaskPoolScheduler.Default as Asti mentioned */));
```

Comment: Hi, thanks, but I have to admit, I am still struggling with obsevables, so it will take some time for me to fully understand. But does turning each individual item to its own observable makes sense?

Comment: An observable is more a concept than a physical thing: It's a stream of items that you handle somehow. If you're going to handle some items differently than others, it generally makes sense to split those off into their own stream. That's what we're doing here.

Comment: In contrast, for example, to threads, where there is a physical thread, each one incurs a cost in turns of computation and memory. The question you should really be asking is if you need a new thread for each item.

Answer (score 1):

For a simple question, the answer is not quite so.

`ToObservable` essentially checks if the scheduler optimization called `ScheduleLongRunning` is available - which as the name suggests, is to run a single task which might run for long and thus block the scheduler. Otherwise, it has to recursively schedule the enumeration which is an order more inefficient.

And here comes `NewThreadScheduler` which is an ideal candidate to support `ScheduleLongRunning` - it just has to run the whole thunk on a new thread.

The end result is that ultimately all the work gets scheduled in *one* thread.

Finally, `NewThreadScheduler` is overkill for enumerations, so you might want to want to switch to `TaskPoolScheduler`. But wait, the same optimization runs the whole thing on *one* `Task`.

So `ToObservable(TaskPoolScheduler.Default.DisableOptimizations())`.

P.S.

Not related to the question, but the `Do` method along with a whole bunch of useful operators are in the `System.Interactive` package. If you don't want to install a whole package, `Do` is simply

```
public static IEnumerable<T> Do<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, Action<T> sideEffect)
{
    foreach (var value in source)
    {
        sideEffect(value);
        yield return value;
    }
}
```